# ImageView with footer

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I want to make a layout that fills up with entire screen, but have like a text right below the image, so it would look like a gallery. The text shouldn't overlap the image, since I have that one right now. Any suggestion?

Comment: attach required layout image

Comment: Please post your existing layout xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:textColor="@color/holo_gray_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Although this wasn't correct, I was able to brainstromed and found a solution that worked for me. thanks!